# Python singularize words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nlp

I want to convert the plural words from my column "Phrase" into singular word. How do I iterate over each row and each item?

```
my_data = [('Audi Cars', 'Vehicles'),
           ('Two Parrots', 'animals'),
           ('Tall Buildings', 'Landmark')]
test = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
test.columns = ["Phrase","Connection"]
test
```

I tried

```
test["Phrase"] = test["Phrase"].str.lower().str.split()
import inflection as inf
test["Phrase"].apply(lambda x:inf.singularize([item for item in x]))
```

My desired output is

```
Phrase:         Connection:
Audi Car        Vehicles
Two Parrot      animals
Tall Building   Landmark
```

Kindly note, I want to singularize only one column **Phase**

Comment: Does it work with `test["Phrase"].apply(lambda x:[inf.singularize(item) for item in x])` instead?

Comment: @xdze2 Thanks, yes it works , however I have to join those words too. So the answer provided by vivek below works as desired

Comment: @xdze2 as explained the `x` in your comment in the list comprehension needs to be `x.split()` and then a `' '.join()` outside

Comment: How about doing `rstip() `, something like this `test['Phrase'] = test['Phrase'].apply(lambda x:x.rstrip("s")) ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight change -

```
test['clean'] = test['Phrase'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([inf.singularize(item) for item in x.split()]))
```

**Output**

```
           Phrase Connection          clean
0       Audi Cars   Vehicles       Audi Car
1     Two Parrots    animals     Two Parrot
2  Tall Buildings   Landmark  Tall Building
```

**Explanation**

In your existing code, you are doing this -

```
test["Phrase"].apply(lambda x:inf.singularize([item for item in x]))
```

Let us take the first example and see what happens. `x` in this case will be `Audi Cars` -

`[item for item in x]` returns a list of characters - `['A', 'u', 'd', 'i', ' ', 'C', 'a', 'r', 's']` so `singularize` doesn't work as it is only on characters.

Trick was to do `x.split()` which splits words and then put the `singularize` inside the list comprehension.

Finally do a `' '.join()` to get back the string.

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly fine and I appreciate your great explanation too, In this case I don't need to write test["Phrase"] = test["Phrase"].str.lower().str.split()

Comment: Always prefer to use String Methods (such as `str.lower`) rather than `apply`. Apply is the last resort to always use, as it is slow and does not take any advantage from pandas vectorization